# Making a fish shader in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, shader, scenekit

I am working on a Swift Playground with a 3D model view (Scenekit) and have recently been introduced to shaders (.shader files) for iOS. I've made shaders for Unity before and I was hoping for some help replicating a Unity shader from Shader Graph in the form of a `.shader` file for a shark. Thanks!

Here's a Unity Shader Graph:

[image]

This is the original shader code that I tried for the sinusoidal movement, which didn't work too well, instead it `rippled` in all directions. I tried changing the axis but after that nothing moved for the shader.

```
_geometry.position.xz += _geometry.position.xz
    sin(30.0 * _geometry.position.y - 3.0 * u_time) * 0.05
    (u_time < 3.0 ? u_time / 3.0 : 1.0);
```

This shader was saved as a .shader file and added to my mesh.

Comment: Shader modifiers are the right tool for that. That said the equations in the attached snippet don't seem to match the ones in the Unity graph.

Comment: That's correct. It was my previous attempt, however it didn't work, whcihc is what I was hoping for help with. I couldn't find anything about it online either. I don't know what these .shader files are called for more syntax context.

Comment: where did you put these lines? In the SceneKit editor or using code? As-is they should not compile (there are missing operators between `_geometry.position.xz` and `sin` for instance). Please update the question with more details about how you applied the shader.